Trouble installing Nighthawk AXE3000 WiFi USB Adapter
I am having issues installing my new ASX 3000 WiFi USB Adapter into my Acer Aspire XC-1760 desktop.
I am running Ubuntu 24.04 LTS with kernel 6.8.0.40-generic.
Linux Aspire-XC-1760 6.8.0-40-generic #40-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Jul  5 10:34:03 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

if I run  lshw -C Network I get the Wired network
  *-network                 
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8211/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   logical name: enp1s0
   version: 15
   serial: 88:ae:dd:81:55:65
   size: 1Gbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=6.8.0-40-generic duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.1.128 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
   resources: irq:16 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:84004000-84004fff memory:84000000-84003fff

And the Wireless network device
 *-network
   description: Wireless interface
   physical id: 6
   bus info: usb@2:4
   logical name: wlx941865601368
   serial: 94:18:65:60:13:68
   capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=mt7921u driverversion=6.8.0-40-generic firmware=____010000-20240219111038 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11

When i run ip addr i can see that the WiFi interface is DOWN
: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host noprefixroute 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

2: enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 88:ae:dd:81:55:65 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.128/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp1s0
       valid_lft 83930sec preferred_lft 83930sec
    inet6 fe80::8aae:ddff:fe81:5565/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

3: wlx941865601368: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 94:18:65:60:13:68 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

As you can see the third device, wlx941865601368, shows with a state of DOWN
the device shows upo in lsusb as well
lsusb -v | grep -i netgear
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0846:9060 NetGear, Inc. Wireless_Device
idVendor           0x0846 NetGear, Inc

Can someone tell me what I am missing? It seems to me that the Kernel is seeing the device; it is recognized, just not enabled.
I want to dump the wired connection and replace it with WiFi, as I am using Power Adapters to move data around my home and I get a faster connection over WiFi than I do over the Wired connection as can be seen from the picture below.

Using WiFi, I get 560Mbps, whereas the wired connection travelling around the mains gets me 170Mbps. Yes, latency under load in the WiFi test is higher than a wired connection, but I am not doing time-sensitive work, so that is not an issue for me.
All help is gratefully accepted.

I am not sure why anyone would want to switch from ethernet to wifi on a desktop computer

I dislike the part about SO where people post unhelpful comments to get points. Let's make this a bit more educational.
I said wired connection, not Ethernet. Ethernet is a standard for the transition of data over a physical medium. It falls under the IEEE 802 standard.
Our standard depends on the physical medium over which we will transmit data. I am using IEEE 801.2ab (Gigabit ethernet) on a wired connection. On the WiFi connection, I will be using IEEE 802.11ax, otherwise known as WiFi 6e
The physical properties of the location often define the choice of medium.

Any result after sudo ifconfig wlx941865601368 up  Anything show blocked for rfkill list

Hey @jeremy31 Thanks for getting baclk to me. I have updated the post with the commands you askked me to run. the "ifconfig wlx941865601368 up" did not return anything and the interface is still down  I have posted a post command ifconfig as well. rfkill shows no issues

Any results from terminal for sudo dmesg|egrep -i 'mt76|mt79'

Sorry J@eremy21, I was a complete muppet!!! In the networking control panel in Ubuntu, I noticed that the device was there. I then realised that I had not joined a WiFi network. As soon as I joined a network, I was given an IP address, and it has been working fine ever since. Thank you so much for your help..

The actual fault here was that I had not joined a WiFi network. Therefore, I did not have an IP address!!!. Silly me.
All working now
